# SQL query to calculate time spans based upon time stamps

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

In my project, I have need of calculating a time span. Currently, I'm retrieving every TimeStamp that matches my query and storing them in a `List<>`. Then, I iterate through the list to see if any intervals are 10 seconds or less, and then I add those together. Anything greater than 10 seconds is ignored. I'm wondering if there is a SQL query that I can do that will do this for me? I've done some searching, but didn't find anything. Essentially, I'd like to not have to store so much information in memory if I don't have to. Here's the method I'm using to iterate through my `List<>`:

```
private static TimeSpan TimeCalculations(IList<DateTime> timeStamps)
{
    var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    var totalTime = new TimeSpan();

    for (var j = 0; j < timeStamps.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (timeStamps[j + 1].Subtract(timeStamps[j]) > interval) continue;
        var timeDifference = timeStamps[j + 1].Subtract(timeStamps[j]);
        totalTime = totalTime.Add(timeDifference);
    }

    return totalTime;
}
```

The data that is being retrieved currently can be anywhere from 10 to 400k rows worth of data. Here is a sample:

```
2006-09-07 11:46:09
2006-09-07 11:46:19 - 10 seconds
2006-09-07 11:46:20 - 1 second
2006-09-07 11:46:36

2006-09-07 11:47:49
2006-09-07 11:47:53 - 4 seconds
2006-09-07 11:48:02 - 9 seconds
2006-09-07 11:48:15
2006-09-07 11:48:29
2006-09-07 11:48:34 - 5 seconds

2006-09-07 11:54:29
2006-09-07 11:54:39 - 10 seconds
2006-09-07 11:54:49 - 10 seconds
2006-09-07 11:54:59 - 10 seconds
```

This would result in about 59 seconds. This is the kind of result I'm looking for.

The database I'm using is SQLite.

**EDIT**

Looking at the answers, I can tell that my question wasn't quite thorough enough. My current query to get the TimeStamps is sufficient. What I'm looking for is a query to add the difference between them together, if the interval is 10 seconds or less.

Comment: Can you give us some more details about the data you want to be working with in the database?  Table structure, sample data, desired result from that sample data would be a good start...

Comment: hmmm are you able to use the linq library?

Comment: @Nomad101 Yes, I can.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you asking for rows where the next contiguous row's stamp is less than 10 seconds apart?

Comment: @Matthew: Currently, no. I'm just straight up getting every TimeStamp that matches my query.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P but you want to filter based on the span between stamps... Between *which* stamps? It looks to me like you're after the ones which happen to be in the next row.

Comment: @Matthew: Now I get your question. Yes, I'm looking for contiguous stamps less than 10 seconds apart.

Comment: Will you actually reduce mem usage by making it a query? you say you're using SQLite, could we take from this that your database is running within your application?

Comment: @Alternator: No, the database isn't running in the application. And the hope is that yes, it will reduce memory usage, as well as reduce the time needed to produce the result.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P Just to be clear then, it doesn't matter if the query returns the rows in questions, just needs to return the total time difference? i.e., from your sample data if the query returns '59' then that's all you need?

Comment: @SOfanatic: That's correct. I only need the total time difference, not all the rows.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P check my answer for the 2nd edit then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used your sample data to create a `sqlfiddle` and this query works against your sample data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl.timestamp FROM main_tbl tbl
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT temp.ID, temp.timestamp FROM main_tbl temp
)test 
ON tbl.timestamp <= datetime(test.timestamp, '+10 seconds')
AND tbl.timestamp >= datetime(test.timestamp, '-10 seconds')
AND tbl.ID <> test.ID
ORDER BY tbl.timestamp
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/049f5/3

EDIT 2:

```
SELECT
sum(
  strftime('%s',
    (
    SELECT min(temp.timestamp)
        FROM main_tbl temp
        WHERE temp.timestamp > tbl.timestamp
    )
  ) - strftime('%s',tbl.timestamp)
) as total_sum
FROM main_tbl tbl
WHERE (
  strftime('%s',
    (
      SELECT min(temp.timestamp)
      FROM main_tbl temp
      WHERE temp.timestamp > tbl.timestamp
    )
  ) - strftime('%s',tbl.timestamp)
) <= 10 
AND date = "2013-05-13" 
AND col1 = col2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/049f5/55

Comment: Will this add the differences together as well?

Comment: I'm really digging the second edit. My only question now is, where would I put the additional requirements for the query? Right now my query is `SELECT timestamp FROM table WHERE date = "2013-05-13" AND col1 = col2;`.

Comment: You add that after the `<= 10` part.

Answer (score 3):

I played with a simple table with int cols t1 and t2 and got the right results from this query, I think. Adapt the penultimate line as needed!

```
SELECT sum(diff) FROM ( 
SELECT  t_1.rowid AS this_id, other_t1 - t_1.t1 as diff
FROM temp AS t_1
JOIN
 (SELECT t_2.t1 AS other_t1, t_2.rowid AS other_id
  FROM temp t_2  )
ON this_id = other_id-1
WHERE other_t1 - t_1.t1 = 1
);
```

It's a triple-nested select. The outer one sums all the differences found. and is just the first and last lines. The second level - from the 2nd line - does most of the work. The inner select delivers a list of table row and timestamp values for the second level to play with.

The action is to sum the differences of all rows that have a "t1" that differs by 1 from the next higher row.

To see the differences themselves, omit the first and last lines and replace the ";"

... forgot to say. t1 was supposed to be the timestamp. t2 was representing "other data".